# Создание и вывод данных из многомерного массива с#

Tags: c#, массивы

Не получается создать многомерный массив. Вернее создать как бы "получается", но вывод сделать из него в определённом порядке не получается. Начало массива оказывается концом(т.е. при выводе массива [1,1] он выводит конец. Порядок вывода это "змейка". Т.е. в таблице 
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
(тут типо таблица 3на 3) нужно выводить 
1 2 3 
6 5 4 
7 8 9
Просто хотелось бы узнать, почему при вводе [1,1] выводится не начала, а конец

```
    using System;

namespace massiv
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int n = (rnd.Next() % 5)+2;//на логику
            int m = rnd.Next(2,5);//более продвинутый способ задать ограничения
            Console.Write ("массив из {0} {1}", n, m);
            int[,] mas = new int[n, m];

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                int f = +1;

                Console.WriteLine("\n");

                for (int p = 0; p <m; p++)
                {
                    int g = +1;
                    mas[f, g] = rnd.Next() % 50;
                    Console.Write("{0} ", mas[f, g]);
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine ("\n\n");

            Console.WriteLine("{0}", mas[1,1]);


            Console.WriteLine ("\n\n");

            int j = n;

            while (j > 0) {
                int k = n % 2;
                int z = 0;

                if (k == 1) {
                    z = +1;
                    for (int i = 0; n > i; ++i) {
                        int jer = -1;
                        Console.Write ("{0} ", mas [z, jer]);
                    }
                }
                else 
                    for (int ke = 0; m<ke; ++ke)
                    z = +1;
                int ob= m-1;
                Console.Write("{0} ", mas[z,ob]);

                j = n - 1;
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            Console.ReadKey();


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `z = +1;` - это то же самое, что `z = 1`. Вы, случайно, с `z += 1` не перепутали?